# Invoke routine in class from other class (not activity) in JAVA for Android

Tags: android, class, android-context

I have ;
- MainGamePanel (Extends SurfaceView)
- Button (class)
- Fruitmanager (class)
- Apple (class)

In MainGamePanel, I check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` I hand it over to the button. Button checks coordinates and sets Touched boolean to true.

In MainGamePanel, I check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` If button Touched = true, I hand it over to the button. Button checks coordinates and.. executes a routine in Fruitmanager. There I go wrong :

This is what the addMoreFruit routine from Fruitmanager looks like :

```
public static void addFruit(MainGamePanel context){

fruitInventory();
//add 10 apples with random coordinates

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
Random Rnd = new Random();
apple nextApple = new apple(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                  fruitResources.get(Rnd.nextInt(fruitResources.size()))));
//add them to the arraylist
MainGamePanel.AppleList.add(nextApple);
}
```

}

It works fine if I call it from MainGamePanel by using `fruitmanager.addfruit(this);` But it doesn't work when I call it from the button class.

I suspect it has something to do with the context. I'm not sure how to fix. I've read up about context and understand it's the 'application situation' where the class was called from. I didn't find a n00b-proof instruction (sorry;) on how to handle something like this, though. Or maybe it has to do with "static" and "non-static"? in the dark here..

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to use fruitmanager.addfruit(this); from Button class?
If this is the case it doesn't work because you pass a Button object to a function that expects a context. In the Button class you should keep a reference to the context, and use it when you try add a fruit.

```
public class Button{
private Context context;
public Button(Context context)
{
this.context = context;
}
....
fruitmanager.addfruit(context);
...
```

From MainGamePanel create a Button like this

```
new Button(this);
```

Comment: colegu, , thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!